# Tab readystate returns 'complete' before first server response

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

I have an add-on which is button-activated. The code is as follows:

```
function handleClick(state) {
activeTab = tabs.activeTab;
  console.log('readystate: ' + activeTab.readyState);
  if(activeTab.readyState != 'complete')
  {
    activeTab.on('load', function(){
      activeTab.removeListener(this);
      start();
    });
  }
  else
    start();
}
```

However, somehow the above code always returns "complete" whenever I ask the tab for its current readystate. I'm absolutely sure the page is still loading, the spinner is still running and I actually have PHP breakpoint enabled with XDebug to make sure my page will never finish loading until I want it to. According to the [Mozilla tabs docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs) the readystate should be "loading", because the PHP is not even finished so the server has not sent back any HTML so there isn't even a DOM.

Update: What i've found out so far is that the readystate returns 'complete' until you get the first server response. Once the initial server response gets back to the browser the readystate changes to "loading". Not sure how to go on from there.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then check the readyState attribute check the progress attribute, i suspect after readyState complete fires before DOMContentReady so after complete you probably have to add an event listerner for `DOMContentReady` or `load`

```
var tab = gBrowser.loadOneTab('data:text/html,<div class="profilist-icon-build-1">backround of this span is of icon on desktop</div><input type="button" value="applyCss"><input type="button" value="removeCss"> Change File on Desktop to: <input type="button" value="Release Img"><input type="button" value="Beta Img"><input type="button" value="Aurora Img"><input type="button" value="Nightly Img">', {inBackground:false});
//start - listen for loadOneTab to finish loading per https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/0f076070bc77abd5e406
var mobs = new window.MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {          
    if (mutation.attributeName == 'progress' && tab.getAttribute('progress') == '') {
      //alert('tab done loading');
      init();
      mobs.disconnect();
    }

  });
});
mobs.observe(tab, {attributes: true});
//end - listen for loadOneTab to finish loading per https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/0f076070bc77abd5e406
function init() {
  //run on load of the loadOneTab
  var win = tab.linkedBrowser.contentWindow;
  var doc = win.document;

  var btns = doc.querySelectorAll('input[type=button]');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(btns, function(b) {
    b.addEventListener('click', handleBtnClick, false);
  });

}
```

Comment: I've tried implementing this, but i'm not sure if it would solve my problem. The context is that i'm not sure if the page is done loading, if it isn't I don't want my code to start. But if it is, would this code still work? It probably wouldn't be firing any mutations if it's ready.

In any case, I've tried using the activeTab.window property to create an instance of MutationObserver, but to no avail. How am I supposed to access this method in my add-on code?